# Referencing a single instance of a class for entire application (Firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am using Firebase as my backend, when a user signs up I create a new document in my Firestore DB and then start a listener on that document. When a user signs out I want to be able to stop listening for security reasons.
I currently have a standard Session listener class that handles Firebase authentication and detects when a user has logged in / logged out:

**SessionListener**

```
class SessionListener : ObservableObject {
@Published var session: User? { didSet { self.didChange.send(self) }}

var carRepo: CarRepository = CarRepository()
var didChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionListener, Never>()
var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
func listen () {
    // monitor authentication changes using firebase
    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if let user = user {
            // if we have a user, create a new user model
            self.session = User(uid: user.uid,name,email: user.email)
            self.carRepo.initialiseUser()
        } else {
            // if we don't have a user, set our session to nil
            self.session = nil
        }
    }
}
...
//Sign in / Sign up methods below
```

I also have a repository class to communicate with my Firestore DB (set up listeners etc.)

**CarRepository**

```
class CarRepository: ObservableObject {

let db = Firestore.firestore()
@Published var cars = [Car]()
@Published var listener: ListenerRegistration?

init(){
    loadData()
}

func detatchListener(){
    if(self.listener != nil) {
        self.listener!.remove()
    }
}
    
func loadData() {        
    if(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil){
        self.listener = db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("cars").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
            querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in  
                try? self.cars.append(document.data(as: Car.self)!)
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
...
//Add user to DB below
```

My problem is that I need to access this CarRepository from both the SessionListener (detect when a user logs out so that I can call **detachListener()**, and I also need to access **CarRepository** in a viewModel to parse the cars array.
The problem is that this is creating two separate instances of **CarRepository** (multiple listeners are being set up for the same document, and only the instance was created by **SessionListener** will have **detachListener()** called. Instead, I want there to be a single object that all classes/structs have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a singleton manager class for the database interaction. In that class, you can have a property of type `[String: CarRepository]`. The `String` key is the path to your document. This way you can guarantee only 1 object per path.

Whenever you think of something that needs to be unique and live with your application, think of singleton.